# Delete everything left of second backslash

Tags: regex

My music collection is organized by artist with separate sub directories for each of the artist's albums

My car doesn't support music in sub directories. I want create a usb stick with music all in root. I would also like to bring over playlists, but they refer to the sub directory structure.

Basically all I need to do is delete everything left of the second backslash.

**Before**:

```
The Pretenders\Pretenders II (Disc 1) [2006 Remaster]\The Pretenders - Pretenders II (Disc 1) [2006 Remaster] - 03 - Message Of Love.m4a
```

**After**:

```
The Pretenders - Pretenders II (Disc 1) [2006 Remaster] - 03 - Message Of Love.m4a
```

I was hoping to do this in notepad++ with a find/replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be all you need. Find and replace the following with an empty string:

```
 .*\\
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Can you explain how it works? To me, it looks like any character followed by a backslash. Why isn't the second backslash escaped? What about the stuff between the 2 backslashes? At a glance, I wouldn't expect it to match my example

Comment: The dot ( . ) matches any character except newline. The star ( * ) matches 0 or more of the preceding element. The double backslash is to match the actual backslash ( \ ) character, since the backslash is a special character in regex. So the entire regex finds all characters that precede a backslash. And if there are two backslashes in the input string then the first backslash gets picked up as part of the (.*) portion. Test it out on regexr.com if you want to learn more.

Comment: I think the key to understanding your question is to know that regex operators are greedy by default. So they'll try to match as much as possible before stopping.